# What is cause of skewed positioning of ThreeJS canvas when browser window is resized?

Tags: javascript, html, 3d, three.js, html5-canvas

Basically I'm trying to align a ThreeJS canvas ( blue background with yellow text ) so that it fits snugly within the transparent cut-out of the green image. This is working well for me so far, however I notice that when I resize the browser window or zoom, the positioning of the canvas becomes slightly skewed. For example, resizing the window smaller will reveal gaps around the canvas on the top and left sides.

Ideally, I just want the blue canvas to always appear in the same relative position as the window is resized.

Codepen demonstrating issue: http://codepen.io/joeycato/pen/pRjmYP

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style type="text/css">
      .app {
         background-color: orange
      }
      body {
        color: green;
        overflow: hidden; 
        background-color: black
      }
      .backgroundImage {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0%; 
          left: 0%;
          width: 100%; 
          height: auto;
          max-width: 100%;
      }
  </style>
  <script src="three-r83.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="imgBackground" src="background.png" class="backgroundImage"/>
    <div class="app" />
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
let game,
  BACKGROUND_IMAGE_WIDTH = 1280,
  BACKGROUND_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 736,
  BACKGROUND_IMAGE_ASPECT_RATIO = BACKGROUND_IMAGE_HEIGHT / BACKGROUND_IMAGE_WIDTH,
  ctx,
  camera, scene, renderer, geom, materialTube, textureTube, mesh,
  canvasMain;

function mainLoop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 256, 256);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);

  ctx.font = '12pt Arial';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
  ctx.fillText('GREEN STENCIL OVERLAYING', 0, 100);
  ctx.fillText('BLUE THREEJS CANVAS', 20, 120);
  ctx.fillText('RESIZING WINDOW SMALLER', 10, 180);
  ctx.fillText('REVEALS GAPS ON SIDE', 10, 200);

  textureTube.needsUpdate = true;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}

function initScene() {
  var demoWidth = window.innerWidth;
  var demoHeight = window.innerHeight;

  // Forcing height to match aspect ratio of original iamge (1280x736)
  demoHeight = BACKGROUND_IMAGE_ASPECT_RATIO * demoWidth;

  if (camera) {
    scene.remove(camera);
  }

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(55, demoWidth / demoHeight, 1, 1000);

  camera.position.x = -110;
  camera.position.y = 30;
  camera.position.z = 457;

  scene.add(camera);

  geom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(170, 210);
  geom.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

  if (mesh) {
    scene.remove(mesh);
  }

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, materialTube);
  mesh.rotation.x = 0.13999999999999999;
  mesh.rotation.y = -0.4900000999999998;
  mesh.rotation.z = -0.04999899999999999;

  scene.add(mesh);

  renderer.setSize(demoWidth, demoHeight);
}

function makeCanvas(id, w, h) {
  let elem = document.createElement('canvas');
  elem.id = id;
  elem.width = w;
  elem.height = h;
  return elem;
}

(function($) {
  $(function() {
    canvasMain = makeCanvas('canvasMain', 256, 256);
    ctx = canvasMain.getContext('2d');

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    textureTube = new THREE.Texture(canvasMain);
    materialTube = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: textureTube
    });

    initScene();
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
  });
})(jQuery);

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  initScene();
});

// requestAnimationFrame
(function() {
  var lastTime = 0;
  var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
  for (var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + 'RequestAnimationFrame'];
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + 'CancelAnimationFrame'] ||
      window[vendors[x] + 'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
  }
  if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
    window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
      var currTime = new Date().getTime();
      var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
      var id = window.setTimeout(function() {
          callback(currTime + timeToCall);
        },
        timeToCall);
      lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
      return id;
    };

  if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
      clearTimeout(id);
    };

}());
```

Comment: I can only see green. Why are you calling `requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);` in 2 different places? Why are you calling `initScene()` from your resize callback? Take a look at [THIS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/ne7gjdnq/)

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, I don't technically need two requestAnimationFrame() calls here, I could simply just call mainLoop() directly. I agree, calling initScene() here is a bit overkill ( the earlier code this was based upon had a set of tunable cameras, I could have cleaned that up more. ) I'll update the codepen now.

Comment: I've updated the CodePen and still see the issue. I should have mentioned that I'm seeing this in Chrome on a 1920x1200 monitor, and resizing the window to less than 1280. I managed to find a workaround for now by lerping the camera settings between two hand-tuned positions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the skewing was a direct result of the body's default **margin** settings.

Adding `body { margin: 0 }` resolved my issue.